# ModX cant add packages manually

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, package, modx, modx-revolution

I have added a package (TinyMCE) to the directory core/packages in my site. I have made sure all permissions are ok.

Then in Package Management I click 'Add New Package' and then 'Search Locally for Package' but nothing comes up.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK scratch that - my own stupidity: I was unzipping the plugin file on my PC *then* uploading it. I should have just uploaded the zipped file.